# Regex for sentence preceded by #

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

Okay, so I'm working on a config file parser where comments begin with a #.
Here's  what I've come up with till now.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%%
#[\w]+                  printf("something\n");
[0123456789]+           printf("NUMBER\n");
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*    printf("WORD\n");
%%
```

Now, in the terminal, when I enter #comment, the output is #WORD. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: did you try to escape it: `\#[\w ]+`?

Comment: I think you mean `#.+` or `#[\w ]+`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, put it up as an answer and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `flex` regular expressions is in the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html). `Flex` does *not* use the same regular expression as Perl, Python, Ruby, Java, or even Posix standard utilities (although it is closer to Posix than the rest). In particular, if you read the documentation, you will not find any reference to `\w`, `\s` or any of the other perl-isms which have crept into regexen.

You will find the Posix equivalents, all of which must be used inside of character classes (`[...]`): `[:alpha:]`, `[:alnum:]`, `[:space:]`, etc.

For example, to recognize a <kbd>#</kbd> followed by any sequence of letters, digits, or underscore characters, you could use the pattern:

```
#[[:alnum:]_]+
```

However, it is more likely that you want the comment to continue to the end of the line, and not just to the end of the immediately following word. The normal pattern would be:

```
#.*
```

which works because in Flex, <kbd>.</kbd> does not match a newline.

Comment: damn. I used to write ocamlexx code and never put thought into the fact that regex terms might change across languages. Silly me.